# makefile : foreach error

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have this in my makefile,

```
 rcFiles =  .vim .vimrc .gitconfig .hgrc .screenrc .Xresources .dircolors .bashrc .ctags .bash_completion.d
 install:
     @$(foreach f,$(rcFiles), [ -f $(HOME)/$f ] || ln -v -s $(PWD)/$f $(HOME)/ ;  )
```

if .bashrc exits and I try

```
 make install
```

I get

```
 ln: creating symbolic link `/home/user/.vim': File exists
 ln: creating symbolic link `/home/user/.bash_completion.d': File exists
```

and the process is aborted.
why no prevented this problem the conditional?

Comment: Add `-f` to your `ln` options ?

Comment: Not really - you're just deleting any existing symbolic link.

Comment: I don't think that will help, as the problem is an existing *directory*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ln -sfvn source target
```

The `--force` flag makes it replace an existing link
The `--no-dereference` avoids creating 'subdirectory' links for links to directory, if the link existed already (useful for the `.bash_completion.d` and `.vim` dirs)

```
rcFiles =  .vim .vimrc .gitconfig .hgrc .screenrc .Xresources .dircolors .bashrc .ctags .bash_completion.d
 install:
     @$(foreach f,$(rcFiles), [ -f $(HOME)/$f ] || ln -v -f -n -s $(PWD)/$f $(HOME)/ ;  )
```

### Alternatively

```
     @$(foreach f,$(rcFiles), [ -e $(HOME)/$f ] || ln -v -f -n -s $(PWD)/$f $(HOME)/ ;  )
```

To not only detect files (`-f`) but also directories. You might want to explicitely check for files and directories `[ -f ... || -d ... ]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ -f $(HOME)/$f ]
```

is true only if `$(HOME)/$f` is (expands to) a *file*.  The things you're getting errors on (`.vim` and `.bash_completion.d`) are *directories*.  Try this instead:

```
[ -e "$(HOME)/$f" ]
```

(The double quotes are not strictly necessary, but will save you grief in the event that `$(HOME)/$f` were to expand to something with shell metacharacters in it.)